# Virtual Piano: The recorded notes are in the correct order but their duration and the pauses are wrong. How can I easily correct the song?

Tags: digital-piano, virtual-instrument

(Note: I mention that I am unable to play any musical instrument in real time and I will never be.)

Can you recommend my a virtual piano (preferably free) that: (1) can record a song as I press the notes with the mouse (or using the keyboard), (2) allow me to correct the notes and (3) rerecord the song by pressing just one key (preferably three or more, just for enough speed) only for giving the correct duration of each note and the pauses between them. So, each time I press the key, the next note is played for the duration the key is down and then a pause is inserted for the interval of time the key is up.

For example, I found [this virtual piano](https://virtualpiano.net/) and recorded a song that you can play if you copy the string below in the Menu -> Recorder Window of this piano and then press Play.

> u{1031}o{1144}s{1383}f{954}s{974}o{1596}u{982}o{1145}s{1055}f{1018}s{1311}o{2631}s{1053}a{999}p{940}a{949}a{1073}a{1112}p{1065}o{1710}g{808}f{1547}d{1440}s

As you will see, the notes are in the correct order (I hope) but the rest is not. I just want now to give the right rhythm to the song. It appears that the virtual piano I used can not do what I want, but there should be other pianos which are able to do it.